# Discord.js How to sense when member of guild changes the activity

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, deno

I want to make a discord bot which is scraping activities of guild members.

So, I read docs of discord.js.

But I don't know how to sense when a member changes the activity.

Is there an example for this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `Client#presenceUpdate` event to track presence updates. See https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-presenceUpdate

```js
<Client>.on("presenceUpdate", (oldPresence, newPresence) => {
    // do something
});
```

Comment: Oh, this is the solution for this question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what kind of activity are you looking for, but any activity it's handled via the event emitter. For example, let's say the user has sent a command via message, you can capture that like this.

```
const { Client } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client();

//event emitter
client.on('message', (message) => {
//do something
}
```

If you're working with VsCode, intelliSense will make it easy to know quickly what sort of events you can listen to. But here's a list of all events:

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-channelCreate

If i'm understanding your question correctly the event you're looking for would be

**[userUpdate](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-userUpdate)**

*Emitted whenever a user's details (e.g. username) are changed. Triggered by the Discord gateway events USER_UPDATE, GUILD_MEMBER_UPDATE, and PRESENCE_UPDATE.*

```
client.on('userUpdate', (oldUser, newUser) => {
// do something
});
```

or also

**[presenceUpdate](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-presenceUpdate)**

*Emitted whenever a guild member's presence (e.g. status, activity) is changed.*

```
client.on('presenceUpdate', (oldPresence, newPresence) => {
// do something
});
```

Comment: Thankfuly your comment, I have confidence for trying to use client handler.